# How to find certain extensions in file using vi?

Tags: linux, vi

I have a file open in the vi text editor. The file is a list of urls, like so:

```
http://some768/path/file.7z
http://some768/path/file1.7
http://some/path712/file2.7z
http://some/path917/file3.xyz.7z
http://some77/path999a7z/file4.xyz.7z
```

How can I isolate or find only the lines with a ".7" extension directly in vi? e.g.

```
http://some768/path/file1.7
```

Answer (score 3):

In command mode, use `/\.7\n`. The cursor will move to next occurrence of a URL that ends with `.7`. Press `N` or `Shift+N` to navigate all occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

In Command mode( press `ESC` and type `/` or `?`  => command mode). Write like

To search .7 from the beginning of file:-

```
/\.7$
```

or

To search .7 from the end of file:-

```
?\.7$
```

then press `N` to search next occurance in vi

Comment: `.` will match any character, not just a dot. `\.` is necessary.

Comment: @hgiesel - here word .7 and that too at the end of line will be matched. and it is matching correctly. Please specify string where you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Anything like that is longer than 1 character, that ends in 7, but not having a dot in front of it. E.g. "67"

Answer (score 1):

The following search string in vi will find any line where .7 is at the end:

/\.7$

Comment: OP doesn't wants to search .7z urls, only .7 is wanted by OP. Correct your answer please.